# Conditional probability of choosing one of two clinics

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, probability, conditional-probability

Two competing clinics A and B treat one disease. After the treatment round in clinic A, 80% of
patients recover. In clinic B, 70% of patients recover after one treatment round. Patients are directed
for treatment by an insurance company to either clinic A or B, wherein clinic A is chosen twice as
often as clinic B.

What's the probability that a client of the insurance company, who needs treatment will get to clinic
A and recover after the treatment round?

**I don't think I have solved this task correctly. Could you guide my thoughts to the right direction?). Below is my strange solution**

P(R | A)=0.8 (After the treatment round in clinic A, 80% of patients recover)

P(R | B)=0.7 (In clinic B, 70% of patients recover after one treatment round)

P(A) = $\frac 23$ (clinic A is chosen twice as often as clinic B)

P(B) = $\frac 13$ (probability of choosing clinic B )

\begin{align}
P(A \,|\, R) = \frac{P(R \,|\, A)\cdot P(A)}{P(A)}
\end{align}

$$P(A | R) = \frac {0.8 \cdot 0.66}{0.66}$$

P(A | R) = P(R | A)???

Comment: Isn't just $P(A\cap R) = \frac23*0.8$ being asked for ?

Comment: Note the probability of having gone to clinic A given recovery is $P(A \mid R) = \frac{P(R \mid A)\cdot P(A)}{P(R)}= \frac{P(R \mid A)\cdot P(A)}{P(R \mid A)\cdot P(A)+P(R \mid B)\cdot P(B)}$ not $\frac{P(R \mid A)\cdot P(A)}{P(A)}$

Comment: You need to use $P(A \cap R) = P(R \mid A) P(A).$

Comment: Thank you guys. Now I see that the task was about finding the probability of intersection of two events $(A \cap R$).

Answer (score 0):

What about this additional task?

Under the same conditions, What's the probability that a client of the insurance company, who needs treatment will get to clinic A and not recover after the treatment round?

Am I supposed to find $P(A \cap \overline R)$?

Then $P(R) = P(R \mid A)\cdot P(A)+P(R \mid B)\cdot P(B) = \frac 8 {15} + \frac 7 {30} = \frac {23} {30}$

$P(\overline R) = 1 - \frac {23} {30} = \frac {7} {30}$

$P(A \cap \overline R) = \frac {2} {3} \cdot \frac {7} {30} = \frac {14} {90} = \frac {7} {45}$